# Is there a way to apply matrix to a separate object using Rect?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm using a `canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)` in my game loop and I'm trying to add matrix to a subclass witch comes from a spriteSuperClass I created.

An example of how I use my object in the game loop:

`canvas.drawBitmap(wheel.getBitmap(),wheel.getDrawingRect()wheel.getPositonRect(), mpaint);`

And this is the wheel class I'm trying to rotate:

```
 public class Wheel extends SpriteSuperClass{

//private int degrees;
// private Matrix matrix;
// private RectF wheelRectFDst;
// private RectF wheelRectFSrc;

public Wheel(Context context){
    super(context,R.drawable.wheel,30);
   // matrix=new Matrix();
   // wheelRectFDst=new RectF(this.getDrawingRect());
   // wheelRectFSrc=new RectF(this.getPositionRect());


}

public void updateWheel(){
    this.x--;
    //matrix.postRotate(30);
   // matrix.mapRect(wheelRectFSrc);

}

/*public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
{
    if (source == null)
        return null;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}*/


/* public RectF getWheelRectFDst() {
    return wheelRectFDst;
}

 public RectF getWheelRectFSrc() {
    return wheelRectFSrc;
}*/
}
```

in the comments you can see what I've tried to do.The goal is to rotate the wheel for a given coordinate witch is a car"bitmap"

thanks for helping

Comment: what do you need `Matrix` for? cannot you just rotate the `Canvas` instead?

Comment: I needed to rotate the wheel bitmap and I though the matrix was the easy way to go with, unless I'm wrong.